# XOR cipher decryption in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xor

I have a base64 string that I have to decode, which is `AwELBwc=`. Using the XOR cipher key given to me, which is `26364`, I have to decode the string to get a number, which I already know (`7813`).

How would this be done in Javascript, where you take a base64-encoded string, run it through a XOR cipher with a known key, then output the result?

Comment: @LukStorms Yes, but the base64 is actually 'AwELBwc='. I'm not sure why `atob('MzA4NDE=')^26364` works, though.

Comment: So in the end, the result had to be '17813' but with the first digit chopped off.  Jup, decoding can be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function below is inspired by the xor character by character method that Terry Lennox used in his answer.

```js
function xorDecryptBase64(base64string, cipher)
{
    let keys = cipher.toString().split('');
    let charCodes = atob(base64string).split('')
                    .map(function(c){return c.charCodeAt(0)});
    return Number(charCodes
                  .map(function(v,i){return v ^ keys[i%keys.length]})
                  .slice(1).join('')
           );
}

console.log(xorDecryptBase64('AwELBwc=', 26364));
console.log(xorDecryptBase64('AwAFAAIEAA==', 26364));
```

Comment: `xorDecryptBase64('AwAFAAIEAA==', 26364);` returns 666640. Not sure if the code is at fault or if it's the base64. The result should be 666666.

Comment: @ethanc Fixed. The problem was that when the length of the characters returned from the base64string was longer than the length of the cypher.  But by using a modulus the index in the map gets corrected.

Comment: @ethanc Btw, currently that first digit is just sliced off. I assume that's correct?  And it's not some other special rule instead?

Answer (score 2):

This code should do what you want:

```js
function base64ToArray(base64String) {
    var bstr = atob(base64String);
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < bstr.length; i++) {
        bytes.push(bstr.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return bytes;
}

let key = [2,6,3,6,4];
let cipherTextBase64 = 'AwELBwc=';
let cipherTextBytes = base64ToArray(cipherTextBase64);

let result = key.map((value,index) => {
    return value ^ cipherTextBytes[index];
});

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Result: ' + result.join();


console.log('Result: ', result);
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer that works; however I now have a base64 string that is 'AwAFAAIEAA==', and the result expected from decoding would be '666666'. When the first character is sliced, it only shows the first 4 characters of the result. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Do you mean the first character from the base64 is sliced, or the result? I don't quite know what you mean :)

Comment: There just seems to be some discrepancy between what you expect and the answers we're getting here.. maybe the algorithm used is slightly different?

Comment: The result array is shifted to get the result. And yes, that might be the case, since these algorithms don't seem to work with these specific base64 strings.

Comment: I think @LukStorms has it cracked!